# Using GCM on Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want develop android chat app with the GCM. I had a series of questions :

> 1) Whether messages are sent only on devices that have Google accounts
>   or devices that do not have a Google account to get the message?
>
> 2) Any restrictions on sending messages or the number of requests per
>   second or minute there?

** Please do not negative points and do not remove my question. I looked on the internet and did not receive a definitive answer. Here's why I raised my question.

Thanks your all my dear friends <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) According to [this post](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client),

- On Android devices, GCM uses an existing connection for Google services. For pre-3.0 devices, this requires users to set up their Google accounts on their mobile devices. A Google account is not a requirement on devices running Android 4.0.4 or higher.

2) According to [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-gcm/kYnWzAS14O0/BpfWpfD-vF0J), there is a limit at "low hundred per minute on a per app per device".

Comment: tnx my dear friend <3 . In the case of option 2 : how many requests per second can we send?

Comment: If we are to interpret the answer as 100 per minute, then it equals approximately 1.5 messages per second. Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Every minute 100 request? It is not too low? 100 requests per second, or every minute?

Comment: More than 100 per minute PER device (per app).